# Where is the actual code for numpy's searchsorted?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find the actual code for numpy's search sorted. I looked at:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L1022-L1075

But the searchsorted function just returns: `_wrapfunc(a, 'searchsorted', v, side=side, sorter=sorter)`

And at the top of the code, `_wrapfunc` is given by:

```
def _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
try:
    return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
    ...
```

Then I lose track. Where is the algorithm itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's splitted somewhat across the sources.

Start [here (numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c)](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/04c43f177dcf156ab85118898d30870a38df70cc/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L1399):

```
array_searchsorted(PyArrayObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
....
return PyArray_Return((PyArrayObject *)PyArray_SearchSorted(self, keys, side, sorter));
```

then follow [here (numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c)](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c2372aff1ea85e8e1d64d8b5ced7e362fd0f4a5a/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L1604):

```
/*NUMPY_API
 *
 * Search the sorted array op1 for the location of the items in op2. The
 * result is an array of indexes, one for each element in op2, such that if
 * the item were to be inserted in op1 just before that index the array
 * would still be in sorted order.
...
NPY_NO_EXPORT PyObject *
PyArray_SearchSorted(PyArrayObject *op1, PyObject *op2,
                     NPY_SEARCHSIDE side, PyObject *perm)
{
...
```

Usually stuff like that is found easily when using github's [search-function](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/search?q=searchsorted&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) (which i often use for numpy/scipy/sklearn and co.), followed by going through the possible candidates, where a bit of experience can filter out stuff early. Here the number of search-results are only 3 pages. I saw way worse results in the past.

Answer (score 0):

To followup @sascha's answer, the final code from [binsearch.cpp](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/f782866009f94a932c980cf15f040aa7d1718e36/numpy/_core/src/npysort/binsearch.cpp#L348) is

```cpp
    while (min_idx < max_idx) {
        npy_intp mid_idx = min_idx + ((max_idx - min_idx) >> 1);

        if (binsearch::map[mid_idx].typenum < type) {
            min_idx = mid_idx + 1;
        }
        else {
            max_idx = mid_idx;
        }
    }
```

`>> 1` should be halving the interval via arithmetic right shift.

BTW, the doc of [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) also mentions that python's builtin [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) uses the same alorithm.
From [bisect.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d38298a9ba1663fe7c9ea5a765dbdb0c6c370f54/Lib/bisect.py#L21)

```py
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if a[mid] < x:
            lo = mid + 1
        else:
            hi = mid
```